# How to slice with date-index and multilevel columns (MultiIndex)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I have a large `pd.DataFrame`, `a`, that looks like:

```
bid        TIT IM Equity HELN SE Equity FHZN SE Equity GLEN LN Equity  
field         LAST_PRICE     LAST_PRICE     LAST_PRICE     LAST_PRICE   
currency             EUR            CHF            CHF            GBp   
2013-12-31           NaN            NaN            NaN        285.954   
2014-01-02        0.7085            NaN            NaN        283.942   
    ...             ...            ...           ...            ...
2014-01-08        0.7990         422.65         511.46        287.875   
2014-01-09        0.8095         421.26         514.35        283.165   
2014-01-10        0.8135         423.35         514.83        291.487   
2014-01-13        0.8065         417.78         515.79        291.670
```

index is `dates` and I have MultiIndex columns with 3 levels (`bid`, `field`, `currency`).

How can I slice:

1. to get a `DataFrame` with all values where `currency == CHF` and `date in ['2014-01-08' : '2014-01-10']`
2. to get a `DataFrame` with all values where bid starts with `HE` and `currency == CHF` or `EUR` and `date in ['2014-01-08' : '2014-01-10']`

I cannot find it in the docs.

Comment: Can you provide raw data and code to reproduce your df, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print df['2014-01-08' : '2014-01-10'].xs('CHF',level=2,axis=1)

bid        HELN SE Equity FHZN SE Equity
field          LAST_PRICE     LAST_PRICE
2014-01-08         422.65         511.46
2014-01-09         421.26         514.35
2014-01-10         423.35         514.83

#sort multicolumns
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)

he = tuple([s for s in df.columns.levels[0].tolist() if 'HE' in s[:2]])
print he
#('HELN SE Equity',)

print df.loc['2014-01-08' : '2014-01-10', (he, slice(None), ['CHF','EUR'])]

bid        HELN SE Equity
field          LAST_PRICE
currency              CHF
2014-01-08         422.65
2014-01-09         421.26
2014-01-10         423.35
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/advanced.html#advanced-mi-slicers).